# SQL, joining two tables and selecting their max

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables

```
customers_bought:
       PID        SID   QUANTITY
---------- ---------- ----------
      3289         11         12
     74591         11         10
     74591         12          1
     74591         23          1
     74591         31          1
     88331         13         21
     88331         31         48

customers:
       PID NAME               
---------- --------------------
      3289 George              
     88331 Alice               
     74591 Jane                
     10234 Able
```

What I need to be able to do is list the customers who bought the greatest number of sandwiches of a single type. I also need to display the customer name, pid, sid, and quantity. This being SQL, of course it's more complicated than it sounds. I'm unsure how to join the two results I have below, here's what I have managed to do:

```
Code:
Select C.pid, C.name, CB.sid, CB.quantity
From customers C
Inner Join customers_bought CB
On CB.PID = C.PID;

Result: 
       PID NAME                        SID   QUANTITY
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
      3289 George                       11         12
     74591 Jane                         11         10
     74591 Jane                         12          1
     74591 Jane                         23          1
     74591 Jane                         31          1
     88331 Alice                        13         21
     88331 Alice                        31         48

Code: 
  Select CB.sid, MAX(CB.Quantity)
  From customers_bought CB
  Group By CB.sid

Result:
       SID                        MAX(CB.QUANTITY)
---------- ---------------------------------------
        11                                      12
        13                                      21
        31                                      48
        23                                       1
        12                                       1
```

Comment: Please add in the tag of the RDBMS you are using. Is this question really [`oracle-sqldeveloper`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-sqldeveloper/info) related?

Comment: Look into the rank https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 Select
C.pid, C.name, CB.sid, ms.MaxQuentity
From customers C
Inner Join customers_bought CB
On CB.PID = C.PID
INNER JOIN
(
Select 
CB.sid,
MAX(CB.Quantity)  AS MaxQuentity
  From customers_bought CB
  Group By CB.sid
 )  ms ON ms.sid = CB.sid  AND ms.MaxQuentity = CB.QUANTITY
```

You can find the Sample code in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef451/16)

Comment: What is the issue? order?. I am wondering how did you add cb.PID, c.NAME to your query with out aggregate function or part of group by clause. is your query at least compiling?